# Android native Contacts application deletes every account contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

My problem is that I try to disallow to native Android Contacts application to delete my application's contacts (which are specified by my application account type) from device.

For that I've specified my own `SyncAdapter` with it's own `Service` and it's meta-data described in `syncadapter.xml`. The value of `supportsUploading` is set to **false** (this way I say that contacts created by my application are read-only)

However, when I try to delete a contact of my application from standard Contacts app I get the message which says:

> You can't delete contacts from read-only accounts, but you can hide
>   them in your contacts list

Everything seems fine until I try to get data of the contact which I previously deleted ("hide") from standard "Contacts" in my own application.

The returned cursor is null because there isn't any row in [`Data`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table associated with this contact's [`RAW_CONTACT_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#RAW_CONTACT_ID). I also check if the contact exists on the device looking for 
it's [`DELETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#DELETED) flag value in [`RawContacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) table and observed that it has been set to 1 which means that contact has been deleted.

As official documentation describes:

> Some sync adapters are read-only, meaning that they only sync
>   server-side changes to the phone, but not the reverse. If one of those
>   raw contacts is marked for deletion, it will remain on the phone.
>   However it will be effectively invisible, because it will not be part
>   of any aggregate contact.

So the problem is that I can't display this contact's data in my application any more because I don't know how to retrieve them from contacts database. If somebody knows how to handle this situation I would appreciate any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So after more meticulous search I found the way to retrieve data for any `RAW_CONTACT` in my application independently of was it deleted from some other application or not.

Using of `RawContacts.Entity` API does this job.

Previously I tried to retrieve contact's data using such logic:

```
public Cursor getContactData(long rawContactId) {
    return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=" + rawContactId, null);
}
```

And this method always returned `null` for deleted contact.

But using [`RawContacts.Entity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.html) such way:

```
public Cursor getContactData(long rawContactId) {
    Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    rawContactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, RawContacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    return getResolver().query(rawContactUri, null, null, null);
}
```

allows to fetch contact's data inside application with appropriate authority regardless was it deleted by 3d-party application or not.

Comment: I'm surprised that this should be true. I'm confused that it is in conflict with [the description on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.html)